# How do I upload old screenshots taken with traditional methods to Steam?

Tags: steam

Steam now has a screenshot-hosting feature, but I've been unable to break the habit of hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> to take traditional TGA screenshots in Team Fortress 2, rather than the new hotkey <kbd>F12</kbd> (the default) to take screenshots for uploading to Steam.

There are a couple of images I'd like to upload, but as they weren't taken using the new hotkey they don't appear in Screenshot Manager. Rather, they're in the old screenshots folder, `%ProgramFiles%\Steam\steamapps\[username]\team fortress 2\tf\screenshots`, in the TGA format.

Is there a way I can import these screenshots to Screenshot Manager for upload to my Steam profile?

Comment: First of all, you can change the hotkey to F5 in *In-Game* section of settings.

Comment: For what it's worth, TF2 now provides an option (in Advanced Options) to send any screenshots it takes to Steam, even if you don't use the hotkey that's assigned to Steam.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. There is currently no official way to upload screenshots to Steam directly.

However, there are work-arounds on the [Steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1770824), with varying rates of success.

I personally would suggest waiting until Steam officially releases a method to do this.

Comment: That's a real shame. Oh well.

Comment: They already allow uploading of artwork, so I suspect they omit this feature for a reason.

Comment: Over 8 years after this question was answered and Steam still has no such function. We truly live in dark times.

Answer (score 10):

Take a screenshot in a game with the Steam overlay. When you exit the game, a window will pop up with your recent screenshots for that game. Just click "View on Disk" and it'll open up the screenshots folder (folders are game-specific and named with numbers). Drop whatever pictures you want (Steam uses .jpg, not sure if others will work) in there, but be sure to make a 200x125 thumbnail of the picture in the thumbnails directory or it won't show up. You may have to restart Steam before they show up but you should then be able to upload them like normal.

Sometimes, I have run into issues, where it assigns a random time that the screenshot was taken, if that matters, and I don't yet know how to fix that. Also, you may have to use the same naming scheme as the normal screenshots (year-month-day_#####.jpg - 2011-09-10_00001.jpg, for example).

Comment: There is a list of screenshots stored somewhere within Steam so you need to replace actual existing screenshot with the new one instead of adding a new file to the directories. Also keep in mind that thumbnail size may differ for various screen proportions but they all have 200 pixels in width (mine are 200x112)

Answer (score 4):

1. Take an in-game screenshot with Steam and then exit game. Open the Steam screenshot manager and choose Last Session > View on Disk. (Make sure you don't upload anything.)
2. Find the screenshot you would like to upload and put it in your Steam screenshots folder. (It should have opened from step 1.)
3. Copy the name of the screenshot you took with Steam.
4. Name the screenshot you took with Steam to something temporary.
5. Paste the copied name to replace/rename the picture you want to upload.
6. Close the Steam screenshot manager and then open it again.

Your picture will be available for upload but in the manager; it will look like the one you replaced. Simply select upload and view online and you will see the correct one.

Comment: This works great, but make sure you also replace the thumbnail version in the thumbnails folder with a 200x112 version of your image or your thumbnail will be wrong online.

Answer (score 3):

Saving new files using the naming convention including thumbnails fails for me: the screenshot manager sees them, but uploading reports an error.

However, I was able to open a screenshot captured via Steam and paste the existing screenshot I wanted over it - save and overwrite and it uploads just fine. Not ideal if you want to do many screenshots, though.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you can find this guide useful. Unfortunately for some games not compatible with Steam overlay this is the only way.

Go to Steam user data folder located in by default in

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata[xxxxxxxxx]\760\remote\ (for 64bit machines)
- C:\Program Files\Steam\userdata[xxxxxxxxx]>\760\remote\ (for 32bit machines)

[xxxxxxxxx] depend on your Steam ID. 760 is the App ID for Steam Screenshot app.

Now you have to find the Steam App ID of the game you want to upload a screeshot. The easiest way is search the game in Steam Store (http://store.steampowered.com/) and look at the number in browser URL address (e.g. http://store.steampowered.com/app/265610/).

If there is no folder already with the same name as App ID you can create it using these structure.

```
userdata
+--[xxxxxxxxx]
   +--760
      +--remote
         +--265610
            +--screenshots
               +--thumbnails
```

So now that you have create the folder structure you just need to save the screeenshot in `screenshots` folder using this format

`YYYY-mm-dd_0000n.jpg`

With n start always from 1 for a certain date. Some examples:

```
2014-08-02_00001.jpg
2014-08-02_00002.jpg
2014-08-03_00001.jpg
2014-08-03_00002.jpg
```

It is important that the date of the screenshot file match the date you are writing as filename. It is also important that screenshot is JPG.

In addition you have to create a thumbnail of the screenshot and save it in `thumbnails` folder. You have to use the same name but the width of the image should always be 200px.

Once you have load all screenshot you have to exit Steam and restart it. It could take a while for you screenshot to be shown on the game library, but you can accelerate the process by launching manually the Screenshot management

[image].

Comment: The file name format has change, e.g. 20190210154059_1. If adjusted like that, Steam recognizes the screenshot but still refused to upload them. :(

Comment: Tested it right now, and it worked for me @wp78de eg: https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2562496000

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is possible in 2020 with [SteaScree](https://steascree.download). Worked great for me.