# Uploading Alien Swarm screenshots in Steam

Tags: steam, alien-swarm

I made a couple of screenshots in Alien Swarm that I want to share via Steam screenshots collection. However, in Screenshot Manager I can't chose "Alien Swarm" game (it's not present in the list).

I was able to locate screenshot files in `steamapps\common\alien swarm\swarm\screenshots`, but I can't find a way to upload them in steam screenshots collections.

So basically I want to know if anybody can give me an advice on that - how can I upload jpg screenshots in my collection? Also, is this a bug in Alien Swarm installation that should be reported? If yes, what is the best way to contact Steam on the matter?

Comment: This question isn't really about Alien Swarm. **[Another question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25965/how-do-i-upload-old-screenshots-taken-with-traditional-methods-to-steam)** is related very closely.

Comment: @BlaXpirit: you are right, I fixed the problem manually and I agree that it's really closely related. I don't mind if my question gets merged/closed as a dup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I kinda fixed the problem myself. First of all, I went to the game and made a screenshot while still in main menu, it appeared in another folder and with thumbnail and was visible in Screenshots Manager. So I just copied over the JPG files from `steamapps\common\alien swarm\swarm\screenshots` to `(userdata)\remote\630\screenshots` directory. Mine didn't have any thumbnails that I presume are needed for screenshot manager, so I just copied my screenshots in Thumbnails dir and batch-resized them to the thumbnail size (220xSomething). I also had to rename the files from `asi-jac6-sewerjunction0006.jpg` to `2011-10-07_00006.jpg` and so on, but I am not sure if it was really necessary. After I restarted Steam my screenshots became visible in Screenshots Manager.

So I guess when you take in-game screenshots in Alien Swarm they are stored inside a game folder instead of steam folder. If you really want them published in your profile, you can do it manually like I did.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot upload simple `.jpg` screenshots to Steam without workarounds (such as [Dyppl's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31904/uploading-alien-swarm-screenshots-in-steam#31907))

Alien Swarm's built-in screenshots or PrintScreen ones are not recognised by Steam Screenshot manager. You should use Screenshot shortcut key from Steam (Settings→In-Game) instead. Then your screenshots can be uploaded and managed easily.